# How do I return a record recently added within the same function?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, pandas.excelwriter

I am using pandas excelwriter to add records to an excel file and am attempting to gain confirmation of the record being added upon completion.

```
def add_mem(self, fn, ln, stadd, city, zip):
    __new_index = int(self.find_memend()) + 3
    new_mem_dict = pd.DataFrame({"Member_ID" : [int(__new_index)],
                                      "Fname" : [fn],
                                      "Lname" : [ln],
                                      "Street_Add" : [stadd],
                                      "City" : [city],
                                      "Zip" : [zip]})
    new_mem_dict = new_mem_dict.set_index("Member_ID")
    new_mem_dict['Zip'] = new_mem_dict['Zip'].str.pad(width = 5, fillchar='0')
    with pd.ExcelWriter(self.excel_file, mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        new_mem_dict.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Members', startrow=writer.sheets['Members'].max_row, header=False)
    _members_added = (self.find_memend())
    _newmem = self.search_memID(_members_added)
    return print('{}\nwas added to database'.format(_newmem))
```

Currently this is just a test code until I get all the functionality I want.  As you can see, I generate a new index for the record then create a the dataframe for the record.  I then add the record to an existing excel db.  Finally, I check the the last record added.  This is where things get screwy.  The record that populates is the record prior to the new record.

I suspected that the file wasn't closing correctly, so I tried adding a close statement.

```
def add_mem(self, fn, ln, stadd, city, zip):
    __new_index = int(self.find_memend()) + 3
    new_mem_dict = pd.DataFrame({"Member_ID" : [int(__new_index)],
                                      "Fname" : [fn],
                                      "Lname" : [ln],
                                      "Street_Add" : [stadd],
                                      "City" : [city],
                                      "Zip" : [zip]})
    new_mem_dict = new_mem_dict.set_index("Member_ID")
    new_mem_dict['Zip'] = new_mem_dict['Zip'].str.pad(width = 5, fillchar='0')
    with pd.ExcelWriter(self.excel_file, mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        new_mem_dict.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Members', startrow=writer.sheets['Members'].max_row, header=False)
        writer.close()
    _members_added = (self.find_memend())
    _newmem = self.search_memID(_members_added)
    return print('{}\nwas added to database'.format(_newmem))
```

However this created  an 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Mike\OneDrive\Documents\Apprenticeship Files\Python project\Library_Mods.py", line 156, in <module>
    Lib_Members().add_mem("Alexis", "Griffin", "470 Washington Avenue",
  File "c:\Users\Mike\OneDrive\Documents\Apprenticeship Files\Python project\Library_Mods.py", line 133, in add_mem
    with pd.ExcelWriter(self.excel_file, mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1322, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1326, in close
    self._save()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 109, in _save
    self.book.save(self._handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 386, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1305, in __init__
    self.start_dir = self.fp.tell()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

But when I try to locate the record using the same 'search_memID' function independently of this function, the record is located. So, now I am stuck on what to try next.  Thank you any help.

Comment: You are calling function `find_memend()` which is not shown in your example code. Also it would be helpfull to see the whole error message (i.e. the line numbers and maby trace).

Comment: i don't suppose the issue is coming from one system starting at index 1 and the other at index 0?

Comment: The  `find_memend()` function just locates the last index in my list of records.  I have tried to simply use the `__new_index` variable which is the new index generated by the function, however, the newest index isn't located while inside the function.  It works fine outside of this function and will locate the newest record added.  It just won't locate the newest record while inside this function.  I added the `find_memend()` to the end of this function only to find out what record it was acknowledging as the last record within this function.

Comment: You shouldn't need an explicit `close()`, doing that automatically is the whole point of using the context manager.

Comment: The variable name `new_mem_dict` is misleading. It's a dataframe, not a dictionary.

Comment: The df is just for testing purposes, eventually it will become a dict.  And yes it should close by the content manager but it does not appear to be which is why I tried the the close in the second code snippet.